# How to annotate a return type as either a class instance or its (unique) subclass instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, static-analysis, mypy

I am writing a python library used by importing and (optionally) sub-classing some of the 'helper classes' it provides. I fail to come up with a design that would properly let static analysis tools properly recognise the types that my 'helper classes' methods deal with. Here's a MWE illustrating (one of) the issues I run into:

### My lib

```py
from typing import Dict


class Thing:
    def shout(self):
        print(f"{self} says AAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaa")


class ContainerOfThings:
    def __init__(self):
        thing_cls = self._thing_cls = get_unique_subclass(Thing)
        self._things: Dict[str, thing_cls] = {}

    def add_thing(self, id_: str):
        self._things[id_] = self._thing_cls()

    def get_thing(self, id_: str):
        return self._things[id_]


def get_unique_subclass(cls):
    # this works but maybe there's a better way to do this?
    classes = cls.__subclasses__()
    if len(classes) == 0:
        return cls
    elif len(classes) == 1:
        return classes[0]
    elif len(classes) > 1:
        raise RuntimeError(
            "This class should only be subclassed once", cls, classes
        )
```

### What I expect users to do with it

```py
class BetterThing(Thing):
    def be_civilized(self):
        print(f"{self} says howdy!")

container = ContainerOfThings()
container.add_thing("some_id")
thingy = container.get_thing("some_id")
thingy.be_civilized()
thingy.do_something_invalid()  # here I would like mypy to detect that this will not work
```

This snippet does not alarm static analysis tools, because thingy is detected as `Any`, but fails at runtime on the last line because `do_something_invalid()` is not defined. Isn't it possible to give hints that `thingy` is in fact an instance of `BetterThing` here?

My attempts so far:

#### Attempt 1

Annotate `ContainerOfThings._things` as `Dict[str, Thing]` instead of `Dict[str, thing_cls]`

This passes mypy, but pycharm detects `thingy` as an instance of `Thing` and thus complains about "Unresolved attribute reference 'be_civilized' for class 'Thing'"

#### Attempt 2

Annotate `ContainerOfThings.get_thing()` return value as `Thing`

Less surprisingly, this triggers errors from both pycharm and mypy about `Thing` not having the 'be_civilized' attribute.

#### Attempt 3

Use `ThingType = TypeVar("ThingType", bound=Thing)` as return value for `ContainerOfThings.get_thing()`

I believe (?) that this is what `TypeVar` is intended for, and it works, except for the fact that mypy then requires `thingy` to be be annotated with `BetterThing`, along with every return value of `ContainerOfThings.get_thing()`, which will be quite cumbersome with my 'real' library.

Is there an elegant solution for this? Is `get_unique_subclass()` too dirty a trick to play nice with static analysis? Is there something clever to do with `typing_extensions.Protocol` that I could not come up with?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need `ContainerOfThings` to be generic:
https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#defining-generic-classes

And then I think it would be better for `ContainerOfThings` to be explicit about the type of thing that it will generate instead of auto-magically locating some sub-class that has been defined.

We can put this together in a way that will satisfy mypy (and I would expect pycharm too, though I haven't tried it)...

```py
from typing import Dict, Generic, Type, TypeVar


class Thing:
    def shout(self):
        print(f"{self} says AAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaa")


T = TypeVar('T', bound=Thing)


class ContainerOfThings(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, thing_cls: Type[T]):
        self._thing_cls = thing_cls
        self._things: Dict[str, T] = {}

    def add_thing(self, id_: str):
        self._things[id_] = self._thing_cls()

    def get_thing(self, id_: str) -> T:
        return self._things[id_]


class BetterThing(Thing):
    def be_civilized(self):
        print(f"{self} says howdy!")
        

container = ContainerOfThings(BetterThing)
container.add_thing("some_id")
thingy = container.get_thing("some_id")
thingy.be_civilized()  # OK
thingy.do_something_invalid()  # error: "BetterThing" has no attribute "do_something_invalid"
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Generics are what I was looking for. "Explicit is better than implicit", I know; however my lib (my framework, maybe?) also provides a CLI script which takes a "importable module name" as argument in which you only need to subclass the generic classes for everything to run, and I believe it is a quite elegant solution in this case. There might still be something nicer than this get_unique_subclass() using metaclasses or something, but this does not seem necessary for now.